# Facing issue with LookUp transformation in SSIS 2019

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am using SSIS 2019 and having scenario as mentioned below
I am using lookup Transformation and with the output of matched columns.

1. I need to check if file exists
2. if File exists, then I need to compare the output of look up transformation with the contents of file   and skip the matching rows and consider only rows which are not matched.
   3)In case file does not exists, then I need to use the output of look up transformation and flow continues.

Can some one please suggest what kind of transformations we can use to achieve above functionality.

1)I tried using script task to check if file exists and if success use another look up transformation but unable to compare with matched columns of above look up transformation with file row contents.

Could some one please suggest transformations to use to achieve above functionality in Data Flow Task.

Comment: You have a reference file and some other data (in a database)? Assuming the file exists, the source data from ? is compared to the reference data and only non-matched data proceeds. If the file does not exist, then the requirement of "use the output of look up transformation" loses me. Can you explain further what you are attempting to do

Comment: The source data is also from file goes through multiple transformations and when it reaches lookup1.lookup1 matched output is inserted into Db. Before insertion we need to verify against a file and filter  with data already present in file and skip those records to avoid insertion errors. if records are not there in file then its is  straight insert into DB. Hope you got what I am trying to achieve .

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it by adding Row number as output column as first step of data flow.
Then I modified the script task to satisfy my below conditions.
1)check if file exists, then compare row number generated with the row number on the new temp file and if it matches the skip iteration and return.
2)If no match found then data is inserted to Db. After inserting the data to db, we will insert data(Rownumber and other columns) to new temp file which we are using the row number for comparision.

here is code snippet

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {

        try
        {
            if (ChecktempFileExists())
            {
                bool rowMatch = false;
                string tempFile = Variables.FTPTempFileName.ToString();
                
                string[] lines =File.ReadAllLines(tempFile);

                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    var values = line.Split(';');
                    if (Row.Rownumber.ToString() == values[0] && Row.ClientID == values[1] && Row.GroupNo == values[2])
                    {
                        rowMatch = true;
                        return;
                    }
                       
                   
                }
                if (!rowMatch)

                {
                   Validate(Row);

                    
                    CreateFormContext(Row);

                    if (Row.ErrorCode_IsNull == true || Row.ErrorCode.Length == 0)
                    {
                        Row.ErrorCode = "OK";
                        Row.ErrorDescription = "Successful";
                    }
                    else
                        Row.Id = 0;

                }
```